# How do I count the number of occurrences of a specific word in a text file

Tags: c++, string, io, count

I'm stumped by an assignment I'm working on and don't even know where to really begin, i think what I have may be completely useless.

I'm trying to read a text file that contains 8 lines of text, each with the word "line" somewhere in the line.  I need to count the total number of times that the word "line" appears in the file.

Code I have so far

```
ifstream file("output.txt");    
int wcount = 0;
string token;
string word(line);
while (file>>token)
    if (word == token)
    wcount++;

cout << wcount << endl;
```

I've been looking at this for hours and searching for every possible solution and coming up with nothing.  Please help.

Comment: Please elaborate on the specific problem. As it stands, you haven't told us what in particular isn't working (your code does look pretty close). A good way to do this is to share the results of your prior attempts to solve this problem, in the form of expected and actual output, or the exact compiler error(s).

Comment: the code runs, but the wcount comes back as 0 at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
string word(line);
```

to

```
string word("line");
```

**Update**

To check whether the file was opened successfully...

```
ifstream file("output.txt");
if ( !file )
{
   // Deal with error.
}

// Read the contents of the file.
```

To check whether the words are being read correctly...

```
while (file>>token)
{
    std::cout << "Read the token: `" << token << "'" << std::endl;
    if (word == token)
       wcount++;
}
```

Comment: did that.  It is still outputting 0

Comment: @user3317237, Check that the file opened successfully.

Comment: @user3317237: then you need to look at each word as it is read.  Your code should be OK with this change, but your definition of word may not match what you think of as a word.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i'm not sure what you mean "your definition of word may not match what you think of as a word".

Comment: I got it.  I think i had a small typo somewhere, because when i cleaned up some other parts of the code all of sudden it returned 8.  working find now.  Thank you

Comment: @user3317237: Have you printed out `word` and each `token` as it is read?  For example, if you have `word` set to `"line"` (that is, the string without the quotes), then the string comparator won't pick up the four characters `'l'`, `'i'`, `'n'`, `'e'` in `"inline-function"` or other combinations like that. The first step in debugging a simple program like this is to make a small test case (5 lines of text in a file), and then print out the key information (`word` after it is initialized, `token` after each token is read). There may be a mismatch between what you expect and what you get.

Comment: @user3317237: And your 'cleaned up other code' is a reason for making an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It gets rid of the extraneous material, and ensures that you can still reproduce the problem with a small scale problem.  Of course, to develop the MCVE, you probably still need the debug printing — or to use the debugger to run the code.